# Slow HDD after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, mount, hard-drive

I've upgraded from Budgie Remix 16.04 to Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 today. I've 3 disks connected to my desktop pc via sata. An SSD that I have my Ubuntu installation on, which works fine. And 2 HDD's (1 TB and a 500 GB both ntfs). The problem is when I try to mount them, they mount very slowly or don't mount at all. Even if it mounts it's very slow to read files or dirs. They used to work fine before the upgrade. I don't know if it's related to the problem but I've heard a slight single bleep when I restarted after the upgrade was complete. Normally the hdd used make noises like drum roll when I mounted it, now it sounds more like a heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I have founded a solution: I’ve changed the sync to async in this /etc/fstab line that I used to tell Ubuntu to auto-mount the disk:

```
UUID=<uuid> <pathtomount> <file system> uid=<userid>,gid=<groupid>,umask=0022,sync,auto,rw 0 0.
```

Comment: To the best of my memory I think I've tried that and it didn't work for me, unfortunately I can't try that or anything else anymore because I've switched to Solus, thanks anyway.